# Why is the base (bootstrap) image so large?

Tags: arch-linux

I am experimenting with containers running ArchLinux. I normally use Ubuntu but was attracted to Arch by the promise of a light, epured distribution.

Indeed, when installing the bootstrap version, there is almost no content (which is great).

To my surprise, the size of this installation is approx. 1.2 Gb, while the equivalent Ubuntu is around 250 Mb

Why is the bootstrap image so large? Can it be easily reduced?

Comment: Try `paccache -rk0` (as root) to delete all the cached packages and check how much space you have freed.

Comment: @cylgalad: 150 MB were freed, bringing the size to 1 GB, which is still huge compared to Ubuntu

Comment: What `pacstrap` arguments did you use? Unlike crap like Ubuntu, you don't need to install -devel packages so packages are a little bigger and if you installed `base-devel` (as recommended) you have the equivalent of `build-essential`. Also I'm really surprised you can have Ubuntu with only 250 MB.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same *issues* as you. I have a version of Debian that I generated with `debootstrap` and the minbase option that is 275 MB. The minbase option installs packages with priority "essential" (something like [this list](https://wiki.debian.org/BusterPriorityRequalification)). I also have an Arch system with only the [base package group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/base/) that is 877 MB and another with only the [base-devel package group](https://www.archlinux.org/groups/x86_64/base-devel/) that is 685 MB.

The base and base-devel package groups are pretty minimal, but not nearly as minimal as the "essential" Debian packages. There are always people complaining that the Arch groups contain too much stuff. While installing the base (or base-devel) group is easiest, there is no reason you cannot pick and choose which packages to install.